# Django2.2 partial data unless port specified (ERR CONTENT LENGTH MISMATCH)

Tags: django, nginx, datatables, django-2.0

**Original:**
*Scroll to see most up to date, this is the original post*

Data tables seem to only be working when navigating directly to my Django web application at http://server.com:9001 even when I've proxied all HTTP traffic to 9001.

Screenshot when viewing from **http://server.com:9001/stores**
[image]

Screenshot when viewing from **http://server.com/stores**
[image]

The datatable just simply refuses to work. What's even more odd is I have another data table at **/servers** doing the same thing, but an identical table at **/closed-stores** works consistently (I've refreshed dozens of times in a row to try and get it to break & it won't).

Each of these tables' JS is simply `$('#table-id').Datatable();` but I'll leave this out as its clearly working, so I believe its my **Nginx.conf** maybe, or something to do with Django?

I'll note as well there are 0 errors in console during all scenarios.

**Nginx.conf**

```
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        #listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
        }

        location /static {
                autoindex on;
                alias /home/usr/applications/it-database/static/;
}
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Its worth noting that these tables have been working perfectly without a single issue for nearly 2 months from my Windows Server 2016 development server, but when moving to CentOS this began occurring. I only include this because I have absolutely no idea what the issue may be.

---

**Update 1:**
After a bit of digging around, I uncovered that the issue is that for one reason or another my *context* data is being cut off somehow. If I specify the port number, I am given all complete data, thus the table can be converted to a data table, but when I don't specify the port number, the data will be cutoff at **Store 386** (sometimes more, sometimes less, always in this area).

[image]

I can see that in certain versions of Chrome, accessing the `/stores/` endpoint will give a `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` error. Much have said that with previous versions this was due to middleware orders, but has since been resolved.

**My middlewares:**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**/stores/ view:**

```
@login_required
def stores(request):
    stores = Store.objects.exclude(street_address__contains="closed").all()
    context = {
        'stores':stores,
    }
    return render(request, 'all_stores.html', context)
```

**Stores Template:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} All Stores - Stores Database {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<br>

<div class="flex_container">
    <h2>Store Database</h2>

    <div class="table_header" style="float: left; position: relative;">
        <br>
        <h4>All Locations</h4>
    </div>

    <table id="store-table" class="table-striped table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Store #</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Zip Code</th>
                <th>Circuit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            {% for store in stores %}
            <tr id="table-row">
                <td><a href="/stores/{{ store.pk }}">{{ store.store_number }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="/stores/{{ store.pk }}">{{ store.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ store.phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ store.city }}</td>
                <td>{{ store.state }}</td>
                <td>{{ store.postal }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% for circuit in store.circuit_set.all %}
                    <p>{{ circuit.circuit_id }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </td>
            </tr>

            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#store-table').DataTable();

        });
    </script>

    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here wasn't necessarily Django related, but more of how Nginx handles proxying with delivering static content. When you set up a proxy_pass for static files, you need to verify that your nginx user has access to `/lib/nginx/proxy_tmp`. There may be other vital directories your user needs access to as well, so I just gave ownership to the entire `/lib/nginx` directory.

The reason it would deliver when specifying the port is because I was accessing my Gunicorn/Django application directly, not proxying through Nginx, so this proxy directory was irrelevant in that scenario.